# PHP file will not echo to page after called using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm still new to PHP and have created a form with a button that executes the following when clicked:

```
$(".changePassBtn").on('click', function() {
       console.log("WORKS!!");
    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/passwordchange.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {

        }});

    });
```

I know this is being executed because the console.log. This then calls ../php/passwordchange.php (Chrome doesn't show any errors finding it) which has the following:

```
<?php

    echo "Hello world";

?>
```

But nothing is echoed. I'm probably missing something simple here; How can I get the PHP to run?

Comment: add `dataType:'text',`

Comment: In your `success` callback try `console.log(data)`

Comment: You have to do something in your success callback with the response. Right now you just discard it.

Comment: @guradio, jQuery uses an intelligent guess as default for dataType, so no need to explicitly tell dataType to be text. skyguy, _But nothing is echoed._ what do you mean nothing is echoed? That php didnt echo anything out, meaning nothing in the Response tab of the network call, or that the javascript console didnt show anything?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Normally when I execute php it prints anything I echo to the HTML page in upper left corner, but nothing is being output

Comment: Also with `new FormData(this)`, since your event callback seems to be on a button `this` is going to be the button not the form. [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) constructor needs to be passed a form element

Comment: Is that the only code in your PHP script? If not check your server error logs, PHP may be silently erroring out

Comment: Nothing is displayed in screen because everything that is echoed in a script called with Ajax will be returned in the "data" parameter in the success function. You need to parse and display it with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

In this function:

```
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{

}});
```

log data, like this

```
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
    console.log(data);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a function when the request finish, and in @hossein barzegari's answer, it will only log the data into the console.

```
success: function(response) { $('.object-to-print').text(response); }
```

When the php destination file echos, this will go inside .object-to-print.